# Implement search effectively in Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to perform a search on my current collection and if the results aren't retrieved i am trying to query my search api

Collection:

```
  var Backbone = require('backbone'),
  _ = require('underscore'),
  Urls = require('../../libs/urls'),
  services = require('../../libs/services'),
  skuListModel = require('../../models/sku/SkuListModel');
var SkuListCollection= Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: skuListModel,
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
    options = _.defaults({}, options, {
      readUrl: Urls.sku.list
    });

    return services.sync.call(model, method, model, options);
  }
});
```

View

```
     searchData: function (e) {
    var self = this;

    var models = this.skuCollection.filter(function (item) {
      return item.get("sku_code").indexOf(e.target.value) > -1
    });
     console.log(models);
    if (models != null) {

      self.skuCollection.set(models);

    }
    else {
      self.skuCollection.fetch({
        data: {
          search_string: e.target.value
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        //self.skuCollection.add(self.skuSearchCollection.toJSON(), { silent: true });
      });

    }

  }
```

My question effectively is how do i modify my current collection to store the retrieved results and if my solution seems effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Move your filtering logic to the collection
2. Use promises to unify your response : an immediately resolved deferred if you find models, the xhr object if you have to fetch the data
3. Customize the behavior of `fetch` via the [`set` options](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-set), e.g `{remove: false}` to keep the existing models

These points lead to a collection definition :

```
var SkuListCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    skus: function(code) {
        var self = this;
        var filtered = function() {
            return self.filter(function (item) {
                return item.get("sku_code").indexOf(code) !== -1;
            });
        };

        var models = filtered();

        if (models.length) {
            // models found : define a promise and resolve it
            var dfd = $.Deferred();
            dfd.resolve(models);
            return dfd.promise();
        } else {
            // models missing: fetch and add them
            return this.fetch({
                remove: false,
                data: {
                    search_string: code
                }
            }).then(filtered);
        }
    }
});
```

Your view would then be rewired as :

```
searchData: function (e) {   
    this.skuCollection.skus(e.target.value).then(function(models) {
        // do what you have to do with the filtered models
    });
}
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/84342xer/1/

Comment: how do i bind the results model to my original list?

Comment: If I understand correctly, that's in the updated version I posted a few minutes ago.

Comment: Thanks.. The filtered models that we get how do i apply to my current collection as the changes aren't reflected on the page

Comment: i have a change and an add event bound to my collection but still

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question : `this.skuCollection` triggers an `add` event you can listen to and re-render you view if necessary